# Ruby regex match specific string with special conditions

Tags: ruby, regex, tokenize, lexer

I'm currently trying to parse a document into tokens with the help of regex.

Currently I'm trying to match the keywords in the document. For example I have the following document:

```
Func test()
  Return blablaFuncblabla
EndFunc
```

The keywords that needs to be matched is Func, Return and EndFunc.

I've comed up with the following regex: (\s|^)(Func)(\s|$) to match the Func keyword, but it doesn't work exactly like I want, the whitespaces are matched as well!

How can I match it without capturing the whitespaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(?:\s|^)(Func)(?:\s|$)
```

`?:` makes a group non-capturing.